# Using Slick carousel, how do I add a class to external nav?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am using Slick JS carousel and it works fine. I have external nav set up to control it. I would like to have an 'active' class added to the `<a>` in the external nav. The class would be added and removed based on what slide is active and/or clicked on.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="slider">
                <div class="responsive">
                    <h3>Responsive</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="resourceful">
                    <h3>Resourceful</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="remarkable">
                    <h3>Remarkable</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="resilient">
                    <h3>Resilient</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="relationships">
                    <h3>Relationships</h3>
                </div>

</div>
<div id="externalNav">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Responsive</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Resourceful</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Remarkable</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Resilient</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Relationships</a></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

And JS code:

```
$('#slider').slick({
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 7000,
arrows: false
});

$("#externalNav li a").click(function(e){
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  $( "#slider" ).slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
});
```

Currently, the active class is added. But it is not being removed when I click on another item in the external nav. `$(this).addClass("active");` is not the correct solution here, but I'm not sure what else will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the slick afterChange event, assuming that the index of the slide matches the nav:

```
$("#externalNav li a").click(function(a) {
    var e = $(this).parent().index();
    $("#slider").slick("slickGoTo", parseInt(e));
});

$("#slider").on("afterChange", function(a, e, i, l) {
    $("#externalNav li a").removeClass("active");
    $("#externalNav li:eq(" + i + ") a").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't quite work. This solution seems to wait until the slider has gone through all the slides, then it adds the 'active' class to the `<li>`

Comment: Just edited above to add a removeClass line which will get rid of the active class on all LIs before re-applying it to the current slide.

Comment: Now, the link gets 'active' added, but then it is removed a second after it is added. It still goes through all the slides and then adds 'active' to all the links. I also tried removing my `$(this).addClass("active");` but then the class did not get added at all.

Comment: I have edited the answer.  This is full working code snippet.